# Please explain output from the `function1(p1,p2,p3);`

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

class coordinate
        {
        private:


    int x;
        int y;

public:

    coordinate()//DEFAULT CONSTRUCTOR
    {
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        cout << "def C coordinate\t" << x << " " << y << endl;
    }

    coordinate(int a, int b)//PARAMETRIZED CONSTRUCTOR
    {
        x = a;
        y = b;
        cout << "prmtzd C coordinate\t" << x << " " << y << endl;
    }

    coordinate(const coordinate &cpy)//COPY CONSTRUCTOR
    {
        x = cpy.x;
        y = cpy.y;
        cout << "CPY C coordinate\t" << x << " " << y << endl;
    }

    void setall(int a, int b){x = a; y = b;}

    int getx(){return x;}

    int gety(){return y;}

    ~coordinate()//DESTRUCTOR
    {
        cout << "D coordinate\t" << x << " " << y << endl;
    }
};
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class point 
{
private:
    coordinate xy;
    int z;

public:

    coordinate &ref = xy;

    point():xy(),z(0)//DEFAULT CONSTRUCTOR
    {
        cout << "def C point\t" << xy.getx() << " " << xy.gety() << " " << z << endl;
    }

    point(int a, int b, int c) :xy(a, b), z(c)
    {
        cout << "prmtzd C point\t" << xy.getx() << " " << xy.gety() << " " << z << endl;
    }

    point(coordinate a, int b)
    {
        xy = a;//this calls default constructor
        z = b;
        cout << "prmtzd C point\t" << xy.getx() << " " << xy.gety() << " " << z << endl;
    }

    point(const coordinate &cpy)//COPY CONSTRUCTOR
    {
        xy = cpy;
        z = 100;
        cout << "cpy C point\t" << xy.getx() << " " << xy.gety() << " " << z << endl;
    }

    void setall(int a, int b, int c){xy.setall(a, b); z = c;}

    void print() { cout << xy.getx() << " " << xy.gety() << " " << z << endl; }

    ~point()//DESTRUCTOR
    {
        cout << "D point\t" << xy.getx() << " " << xy.gety() << " " << z << endl;
    }
};

void function1(point &p1, point p2, point p3)
{

    p2.setall(10, 10, 10);
    p3.ref.setall(200, 200);

}

coordinate co1;

int main()
{
    point p1; 
    co1.setall(100, 100);
    point p2(5, 5, 5);
    point p3(co1); 
    p1.print();
    p2.print();
    p3.print();
    **function1(p1,p2,p3);**
    co1.setall(8, 8);
    point p4(co1, 8);
    co1.~coordinate();
    p1.print();
    p2.print();
    p3.print();
    return 0;
}
```

I need to know how to work **function 1** `function1(p1,p2,p3);`

The OUTPUT is

```
CPY C coordinate 100 100??
CPY C coordinate 5 5 ??
```

Why doesn't it print

```
cpy C point
```

**OUTPUT**

```
def C coordinate        0 0
def C coordinate        0 0
def C point     0 0 0
prmtzd C coordinate     5 5
prmtzd C point  5 5 5
def C coordinate        0 0
cpy C point     100 100 100
0 0 0
5 5 5
100 100 100
CPY C coordinate        100 100
CPY C coordinate        5 5
D point 10 10 10
D coordinate    10 10
D point 100 100 100
D coordinate    100 100
CPY C coordinate        8 8
def C coordinate        0 0
prmtzd C point  8 8 8
D coordinate    8 8
D coordinate    8 8
0 0 0
5 5 5
200 200 100
D point 8 8 8
D coordinate    8 8
D point 200 200 100
D coordinate    200 200
D point 5 5 5
D coordinate    5 5
D point 0 0 0
D coordinate    0 0
D coordinate    8 8
```

Comment: Your explicit destruction of `co1` makes it an invalid program.

Comment: Hi Please refer this [How To Ask Good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) , Good question asked get up voted easily, voted question get more attraction to get good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`point(const coordinate &cpy)` is not a copy constructor.  You haven't provided a copy constructor for `point`.  When `function1` is called `p2` and `p3` will be constructed from the compiler generated default copy constructor.  This will call the default copy constructor for `coordinate` to copy the `xy` member.  This why you get two `CPY C coordinate` output lines.  (Incidentally, the `ref` member of the newly constructed `point` will refer to the `xy` member of the source object, not the one in the newly constructed object.)

If you call `function1(p1,p2.xy,p3.xy);` then you'd see the `cpy C point` you're expecting, as the parameter `point`s will be constructed from the `coordinate`s of `p2` and `p3`.